# Transit flight from a country that doesn't require passport to a Schengen country?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration

Normally, I have a special type of Turkish passport that allows me to gain entrance to some Schengen countries without a visa, and the Netherlands is one of them. I am staying in Northern Cyprus for holidays for last a few days. Three days later, I'll travel to Amsterdam from here. So here's the thing:

When traveling from Turkey to Northern Cyprus, one doesn't need to present a passport even though you still leave the country through international departures. You just present your ID at Istanbul Airport and they give you a paper that works like a single use and only-for-Northern-Cyprus passport. This has two advantages: First, you don't have to pay the exit stamp fee since you don't get your passport stamped and second, you don't have the stamp of Northern Cyprus on your passport upon entrance to the country (I am told that it creates problems entering some other countries, especially Greece, due Northern Cyprus' disputed status).

However, I'm now told by a friend that since I left Turkey without an exit stamp on my passport, it might be problematic for me when I arrive at the Netherlands. Do you guys agree with this? Would they ask me why I don't have an exit stamp in my passport? Or would they deny me entrance to the country there, and send me back to Turkey?

Answer (score 3):

Netherland authorities care about *who you are*, and if you are *allowed in the country*; but very little where you came from and what stamps you got there (or didn’t get).
Many countries don’t have exit stamps, so it is doubtful that they even *know* that Turkey has such a thing.

Comment: And even if they do care about the exit stamp, the OP has a demonstrable example of being able to exit Turkey entirely legally without obtaining one - unless of course Turkish citizens are not allowed to exit Northern Cyprus to any destination other than Turkey....